# You doing ok ? Where is an are?

Tags: grammar

Could somebody explain it to me: where is an 'are' in the sentence

> "You doing ok?"

I find this example in some American cartoon, along with the other examples where auxiliary verb is not in place.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in an informal talk where the purpose is to convey the message and not prove your grammar skills! It's known as [ellipsis](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ellipsis).

> *the omission of a word or words necessary for complete grammatical construction but understood in the context (Ex.: “if possible” for “if it is possible”)*

However, [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ellipsis) says that even after using ellipsis, the sentence should be grammatically complete!